# fatal: Unable to look up android.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)

Tags: android, linux, git, repository

repo sync fails with the following message:

```
repo init -u git://android.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
   Getting repo ...
   from git://android.kernel.org/tools/repo.git
   fatal: Unable to look up android.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
```

I know that kernel.org has been hacked and the source is now under github at http://www.github.com/android, but I have the message reported above

Anyone can help me?

Comment: what about changing the address to git://github.com/android/platform_manifest.git ?

Comment: Changing the address to github doesn't working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found instructions how to get sources from [omapzoom.org mirror](http://pastebin.com/SHYgHSbe). It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Whole kernel.org is down for maintenance. I hope it will be up and running soon.